# Getting stuck in running local server for app engine file

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

So, I intended to get started with my local development server for running the introductory "Hello World" app. But i have been running into issues:

```
XXX-MacBook:hello_world xxx$ dev_appserver.py app.yaml

> Traceback (most recent call last):    File
> "/Users/xxx/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py",
> line 101, in <module>
>     _run_file(__file__, globals())    File "/Users/xxx/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py",
> line 97, in _run_file
>     execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)    File "/Users/xxx/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py",
> line 45, in <module>
>     from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.admin import admin_server    File
> "/Users/xxx/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/admin/admin_server.py",
> line 30, in <module>
>     from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.admin import cron_handler    File
> "/Users/xxx/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/admin/cron_handler.py",
> line 23, in <module>
>     from google.appengine.cron import groctimespecification    File "/Users/xxx/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/cron/groctimespecification.py",
> line 51, in <module>
>     import pytz    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pytz/__init__.py",
> line 29, in <module>
>     from pkg_resources import resource_stream    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line
> 72, in <module>
>     import packaging.requirements   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line
> 59, in <module>
>      MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker") TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Can anyone please help me out here. Sorry, just a beginner.